# How to perform cross validation(K-fold) in julia?

Tags: julia

Suppose I have a dataset with two columns. I have built linear regression model on my dataset, Now my question is how do I check the accuracy of my model.

I found that answer to my question is applying K-fold on my dataset. I know how K-fold works but I have no idea how to implement K-fold in my Julia program.

```
#suppose I have two columns x and y in my dataset

 x= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
 y=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21]

# now how do I use K-fold to split dataset and also evaluate my algorithm?
```

Comment: Adding code to the question increases the speed and relevance of answers. Adding running code is even better.

Comment: I have updated the post with a sample code! I don't think it makes sense to share the source code of my model too!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `folds` from [MLDataUtils.jl](https://github.com/JuliaML/MLDataUtils.jl).

```
kfolds([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],5)
```

Comment: It might be better to randomly shuffle the dataset, or pass the data through a random permutation, to ensure conditions are right to get unbiased results.

Comment: Well yeah. Do that and then use this, sure.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the comment, it is easier to setup some code once any base source is given. For example in this case, K-fold cross-validation might need to go through preparation like the following:

```
julia> x= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];

julia> y=[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21];

julia> K = 5 # number of folds in validation
5

julia> N = length(x) # number of samples in dataset
20

julia> stops = round.(Int,linspace(1,N,K+1))
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
  1
  5
  9
 12
 16
 20

julia> vsets = [s:e-(e<N)*1 for (s,e) in zip(stops[1:end-1],stops[2:end])]
5-element Array{UnitRange{Int64},1}:
 1:4  
 5:8  
 9:11 
 12:15
 16:20

julia> tsets1 = [1:s-1 for (s,e) in zip(stops[1:end-1],stops[2:end])]
5-element Array{UnitRange{Int64},1}:
 1:0 
 1:4 
 1:8 
 1:11
 1:15

julia> tsets2 = [e+(e<=N)*1:N for (s,e) in zip(stops[1:end-1],stops[2:end])]
5-element Array{UnitRange{Int64},1}:
 6:20 
 10:20
 13:20
 17:20
 21:20

julia> σ = randperm(N);

julia> [x[σ[vsets[i]]] for i=1:K]   # validation sets
5-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [5, 13, 6, 10]   
 [16, 4, 2, 3]    
 [9, 19, 20]      
 [17, 12, 14, 11] 
 [8, 1, 18, 7, 15]

julia> [x[vcat(σ[tsets1[i]],σ[tsets2[i]])] for i=1:K]   # training sets
5-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [4, 2, 3, 9, 19, 20, 17, 12, 14, 11, 8, 1, 18, 7, 15]   
 [5, 13, 6, 10, 19, 20, 17, 12, 14, 11, 8, 1, 18, 7, 15] 
 [5, 13, 6, 10, 16, 4, 2, 3, 12, 14, 11, 8, 1, 18, 7, 15]
 [5, 13, 6, 10, 16, 4, 2, 3, 9, 19, 20, 1, 18, 7, 15]    
 [5, 13, 6, 10, 16, 4, 2, 3, 9, 19, 20, 17, 12, 14, 11]
```

This may be satisfactory. For more details regarding K-fold cross validation here is a link to Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)#k-fold_cross-validation

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, I think this is too much of detail. I just wanted to know how do  I use Kfold from packages present in Julia. 
anyways I know how to use Kfold now